# Checking the class of an object of a package in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to check for which all objects are data frames in package called "datasets" and if found for them I want to check for the conditions like if dimensions of those data frames is 248 observations and 8 variables then print those object
This is the code I have tried, but unable to get the output.

```
library(datasets)
lsf.str("package:datasets")

listname <- as.list((ls("package:datasets")))
lst=c()
for(i in listname){
  lst <- is.data.frame(as.name(listname[[i]]))

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you bascially need is the `get` function and the `Filter` function.

```
datasets <- as.environment("package:datasets")
dataset_names <- ls(envir = datasets)
filter_func <- function(x){
    y <- get(x, envir = datasets)
    is.data.frame(y) && all(dim(y) == c(248, 8))
}
Filter(filter_func, dataset_names)
```